# How to change php.ini parameters on ovh webcloud hosting

Tags: php, ovh

I would like send emails from my php webpage. I was doing that successfully on my temporary apache hosting on my PC.I need to change php.ini parameters such as sendmail_from, but there is no clear explanation how do I do that on OVH.

I was able to access php.ini file using SSH but I'm unable to save it (no permission).

I was trying to put .platform.app.yaml in the root folder as well as in the www folder using FTP explorer but it is not working either.

Comment: Maybe an easier solution would be to use one of the tried and tested mail-libraries, like PHPMailer? Then you send the emails directly from PHP to an SMTP server without needing to configure anything specific on the server. Makes it easier to set up and manages while being much more portable.

Answer (score 2):

### Warning

Do not use php internal mail() function, it is cumbersome and mostly lead to errors. Especially when setting mail headers and attachments. It is much less configurable (as you are experiencing now) and is impossible to use modern smtp that require OAuth2.

Better use well tested php library like:

- [symfony/mailer](https://github.com/symfony/mailer)
- [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

### How to change php ini setting

Attention, not all hosting provider allow changing php.ini settings, therefore this is not sure if this will work.

The function to use is [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

You need to set the sendmail_from, normally this should be done via email header. But many smtp replace the from address with the one used for the authentication.

Comment: Just an add-on. PHP's internal mail() doesn't support _any_ type of authentication, it being oauth2 or even just normal username/password.

Comment: As far as I remember it has user/password setting in php.ini, but probably I'm wrong, it is ages that I do not use it.

Comment: I think you can set up sendmail to act as a proxy for SMTP, but that would be done in sendmail, not in PHP. PHP has no settings for SMTP authentication.